# React Tour get wrong position when using with Slide transition in Dialog Material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dialog, material-ui

As described, I'm using `react-tour` to implement a guidance for my project.

The First step is a small component that stays inside a `<Dialog />` that needs to be highlighted. But due to the transition, `react-tour` miscalculated the position. If I use the keyboard `Right/Left` arrow, it will re-calculate again and show up correctly.

I've put a short sample here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-tour-with-dialog-material-ui-dbtkh

In line 109, if I comment out this line `TransitionComponent={Slide}`, it will work because the default transition is `Fade`. The problem is from the beginning, the initial animation we've chosen is Sliding Up and it applied globally . I just cannot simply change this.

I cannot find a method or API to recalculate from the [main repo site.](https://github.com/elrumordelaluz/reactour)

Any workaround for this, I'd really appreciate

```js
import React from "react";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Dialog from "@material-ui/core/Dialog";
import MuiDialogTitle from "@material-ui/core/DialogTitle";
import MuiDialogContent from "@material-ui/core/DialogContent";
import MuiDialogActions from "@material-ui/core/DialogActions";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import CloseIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Close";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Slide from "@material-ui/core/Slide";
import Tour from "reactour";

const Transition = React.forwardRef(function Transition(props, ref) {
  return <Slide direction="up" ref={ref} {...props} />;
});

const tourConfig = [
  {
    // updateDelay: 1500,
    selector: '[data-tut="reactour__iso"]',
    content: `Ok, let's start with the name of the Tour that is about to begin.`
  },
  {
    selector: '[data-tut="reactour__logo"]',
    content: `And this is our cool bus...`
  }
];

export default function CustomizedDialogs() {
  const accentColor = "#5cb7b7";
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [isTourOpen, setTourOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };
  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };
  const closeTour = () => {
    setTourOpen(false);
  };
  const openTour = () => {
    handleClickOpen(true);
    setTourOpen(true);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button variant="outlined" color="secondary" onClick={openTour}>
        Open Tour
      </Button>
      <Tour
        onRequestClose={closeTour}
        disableInteraction={false}
        steps={tourConfig}
        isOpen={isTourOpen}
        maskClassName="mask"
        className="helper"
        rounded={5}
        accentColor={accentColor}
      />
      <Dialog
        TransitionComponent={Slide} //Removing this effect will correct the behavior
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="customized-dialog-title"
        open={open}
      >
        <DialogTitle id="customized-dialog-title" onClose={handleClose}>
          Modal title
        </DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent dividers>
          <Typography data-tut="reactour__iso" gutterBottom>
            Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio,
            dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta
            ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.
          </Typography>
          <Typography gutterBottom>
            Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.
            Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor
            auctor.
          </Typography>
          <Typography gutterBottom>
            Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Praesent commodo
            cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec sed odio
            dui. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.
          </Typography>
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button
            data-tut="reactour__logo"
            autoFocus
            onClick={handleClose}
            color="primary"
          >
            Save changes
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but I give a timeout to the first part of the tour equal transition time and that works for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30853583)

Answer (score 0):

you can add timeout before open the tour.

```
const openTour = () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    setTourOpen(true);
  }, 2000)
};
```